# bgp and incomming requests

Tags: high-availability, bgp, mikrotik, routeros

I have IP pool, 2 providers and BGP on RouterBoard.
First provider is default. Second is backup.
If first provider falls - outgoing connections works on second. But *incoming* still routed to broken provider.

How to made higher available server?

Comment: You purchased an IP allocation from IANA/RIR - Or did you get assigned IPs from the first ISP?

Comment: @ChrisS from RIPE agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason for this issue is mising route object in RIPE Database [Ripe DB search](https://apps.db.ripe.net/search/query.html). Check there if all prefixes, which are advertised by your BGP router, are present in DB as route objects.

Second step: check that you are advetrising prefixes to both providers. command should look like `routing bgp advertisements print <peer_name>`

Third step: If your providers have looking glass service - check if both of them receive your announces and have routes to your IP block.

Following these steps you ought to find possible reason. Post updates if neither of steps cant help.